# How to wait for the execution of method and then exit?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, .net, docker

I have a console application (dotnet core, ubuntu), that looks like following:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var job = new Job();
        job.Start();

        while(Console.ReadLine() != "quit");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //some handling
    }
}
```

While `Job` is implementation of `JobAbstract` class:

```
public class JobAbstract
{
    private readonly int _periodMs;

    protected JobAbstract(int periodMs)
    {
        _periodMs = periodMs;
    }

    public bool Working { get; private set; }

    public abstract Task Execute();

    private void LogFatalError(Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            //logging
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private async Task ThreadMethod()
    {
        while (Working)
        {
            try
            {
                await Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                LogFatalError(exception);
            }
            await Task.Delay(_periodMs);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        if (Working)
            return;
        Working = true;
        Task.Run(async () => { await ThreadMethod(); });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Working = false;
    }
}
```

`Job` is defined like:

```
public class Job : JobAbstract
{
    public Job(periodMs) : base(periodMs)
    {}

    public override async Task Execute()
    {
        await SomeTask();
        OtherKindOfJob();
        await MaybeMoreAsyncTasks();
        // etc
    }
}
```

It all works fine, as you might expect.

Now, I'm wrapping it all up in docker containers for continuous delivery. `docker stop` might be run on a container while `Execute` method of `Job` is run. In order to wait for the cycle to end and then exit gracefully, I've decided to use this approach:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ended = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    var starting = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ctx =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Unloding fired");
        starting.Set();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for completion");
        ended.Wait();
    };

    System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for signals");
    starting.Wait();

    System.Console.WriteLine("Received signal gracefully shutting down");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    ended.Set();
}
```

I've tested it and it works, when calling `docker stop`, docker daemon sends `SIGTERM` signal to the process #1 of the container (which happens to be my app) and CoreCLR invokes `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading` event which is handled appropriately.

So I have a working app and a way (theoretically) how to stop it. I'm just not sure, how should I implement it for a given context. Should I send some kind of token to the `Job`? I want the run flow to be like following:

1. The app is running normally.
2. `SIGTERM` is received. If `Execute` isn't running, stop the app, if it is - wait for it to end.
3. When the `Execute` ends, end the app.

How this kind of thing should be implemented? Please advice some kind of scheme or pattern to achieve that. Thanks in advance!

---

So, I figured something out: what if I add `public Task CurrentIteration { get; private set; }` and change `Execute();` to:

```
CurrentIteration = Execute();
await CurrentIteration;
```

and after `starting.Wait();` in stopping sample, add:

```
job.Stop();
await job.CurrentIteration;
```

Will that work? Are there any issues with the following approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I assume the whole logic of your application can be expressed as single `Task Execute()`. And what you need is pretty simple [task cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) scheme.

Your code might look like :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Start();
}

public static async void Start()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var starting = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ctx =>
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Unloding fired");
        cts.RequestCancellation();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for completion");
        ended.Wait();
    };

    // run application
    try
    {
        await Execute(cts.Token);
    }
    catch(TaskCancellationException ex)
    {
        // cancelled
    }

    ended.Set();
}
```

What I don't like is how you handle the stopping "signal" from the docker. I don't like that you basically "deadlock" the `Unloading` event till the application quits. But I don't know if there is any other way as I don't have experience with docker and never had to handle "graceful" shutdown when application is terminated using `SIGTERM`. Edit : Looking at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2688), your approach seems to be only real way to handle it. There is even one guy doing it same way as I suggest.

Comment: As you can see, invocation of Execute method is in a while loop, because it's a job and it's supposed to be run multiple times.

Comment: Also, is it allowed/adviced to await for the same Task from different threads, like I'm doing in my proposed solution (see edit)?